# Unknown Type Error in OCaml

Tags: list, types, ocaml

I'm attempting to create a new list of all the unique items from another list. My in_list function works properly and returns a value saying whether or not the value is found in the seen_list, but I can't for the life of me get this to compile.

```
let uniq x = match in_list x seen_list with
    | true -> seen_list
    | false -> seen_list@[x]
    | _ -> seen_list
;;

List.iter uniq check_list;;
```

The problem is some sort of type error. Here it is:

```
Error: This expression has type int -> int list
       but an expression was expected of type int -> unit
       Type int list is not compatible with type unit
```

Answer (score 1):

In essence you want to take the result returned by `uniq` and pass it as the list for the *next* call of `uniq`. To do this, you need to use a fold, or write your own recursion. The purpose of `List.iter` is just to call an imperative function for each element of a list. It doesn't combine the answers in any way. That's why you're getting a type error—your function isn't imperative. I.e., it doesn't return unit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
let rec uniq_list lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs ->
      let r = uniq_list xs in
      if in_list x r then r else x :: r
```

Or, using [`List.fold_right`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALfold_right) (equivalent to the recursive function above):

```
let uniq_list lst =
  List.fold_right
    (fun x r -> if in_list x r then r else x :: r)
    lst
    []
```

Or using [`List.fold_left`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALfold_left) which is tail-recursive:

```
let uniq_list lst =
  List.fold_left
    (fun r x -> if in_list x r then r else x :: r)
    []
    lst
```

By the way, your `in_list` is equivalent to the standard library function [`List.mem`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALmem).